# How to enquote the thr exported csv columns using Teradata Tdload utility?

Tags: teradata

I am using the **Tdload** utility of Teradata to extract data from database to a csv file.
The syntax which I have used in the command line is:

```
tdload --SourceTdpid 192.168.xx.xxx --SourceUserName dbc --SourceUserPassword dbc --SourceTable Database.TableName--TargetTextDelimiter "|" --FileWriterFileSizeMax 10M --TargetFilename "file.csv" My_Unload_Job
```

which works fine, but I also want the columns within double quotes.

For example - 1234 should be "1234".

What additional attribute can be added to the command line syntax to achieve this?

Comment: `--FileWriterQuotedData "Y"` - see the [TPT Reference](https://docs.teradata.com/r/AR2bcmSp1Ht~gkgjVNhqig/nMJ~H0VluYv6B_YOBKs2DA) for variable names that can be appended to the FileWriter prefix.

Comment: `tdload` was implemented to allow a quick load without writing a full script. In your case it's probably better to write all your defaults in a simple TPT script called by `tbuild` providing just the database/tablename in a job file.